# Message "Restricted HTML" on node/add page

Tags: nodes, 8

On node/add page for any content type(Article, Basic page. Custom)  message appearing "Restricted HTML" , not able to add content.

What shall a do to resolve this problem?

Comment: It seems you have xdebug enabled, the default setting of that is too low for Drupal 8, you need to add xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200 or so to your php.ini. Have a look at
https://www.drupal.org/node/2413373

Answer (score 1):

Please try again after raising xdebug.max_nesting_level to 500 or so.

Steps:

**Know where is the php.ini:**

In your drupal site go to admin/reports/status/php

[image]

**Then edit your php.ini** in this case, is on /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

Search the xdebug section:

Change the variable xdebug.max_nesting_level to 500 or add it.
[image]

**Restart the web server.**